# How do I get the achievement "In my days" in Another Case Solved?

Tags: achievements, another-case-solved

For this achievement I have to dress up as an old timer but I chose the female setting and no matter what kind of looks I make I can't get the achievement. I know the game is old, but I just started playing it.